# React loading initial state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React. I'm facing an issue of which I (think I) know what is going wrong though I can't seem to find a solution.

What I want to acheive is a datagrid with three buttons on top. Every button changes the grid with data via an api call. Now this button part works well, it's the initial loading where it goes wrong.

So I have a page generating a the component which generates the datagrid. This component needs data generated by a different api call. So the first fraction of a second, there is no data yet. However, it IS mounting the component with null data.

Since it cannot find anything with null data, it will perpetually stay in loading mode, but it will also not notice it has new data to go with (it's not a state change apparently).

I just need the component to go with the data from the first button initially, that is IF it has data.

**Page:**

```
    function CompanyDetails() {
    let { ticker } = useParams();

    let company = CompanyByTicker(ticker); // returns object
    let statements = StatementsByKey(company.company_id); // returns object
    let statement = StatementComponent(statements);

    return (
        <div className='pagebase'>
            {company.name}
            {statement}
        </div>
    );
}


export default CompanyDetails;
```

**Component**

```
function StatementComponent(statements) {
    const StatementLoading = StatementLoadingComponent(Statement);

    const [appState, setAppState] = useState({
        id: 0,
        loading: false,
        statement: null,
    });

    function setId(stid){
        setAppState({ id: stid })
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setAppState({ loading: true });
        if (appState.id > 0) {
            const apiUrl = domain + 'api/statements/single/' + appState.id + '/';
            fetch(apiUrl)
                .then((data) => data.json())
                .then((statement) => {
                    setAppState({ loading: false, statement: statement });
                })
        }
    }, [setAppState, appState.id]);

    return (
        <Container sx={{ height: 500 }}>
            <h2>Financials</h2>
            <button onClick={() => setId(statements.one_id)}>{statements.one_type}</button>
            <button onClick={() => setId(statements.two_id)}>{statements.two_type}</button>
            <button onClick={() => setId(statements.three_id)}>{statements.three_type}</button>
            <StatementLoading isLoading={appState.loading} statement={appState.statement} />
        </Container>
    );
}


export default StatementComponent;
```

I hope someone can help me out...

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that react-hooks setState does not work like setState in class components. Calling setState with React Hooks replaces the WHOLE STATE, and does not merge the objects. You should do this instead

```js
    function setId(stid){
        setAppState({ ...appState, id: stid })
    };
```

And do something similar every time you call `setAppState`.

In addition, you should not be calling your components like normal function (i.e `StatementComponent()`). React hooks will not work properly like this. See [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/never-call-a-react-function-component-6815a92b7856). Instead, you need to use JSX (i.e `<StatementComponents />`. Your code should look something like this:

```
function CompanyDetails() {
    return (
        <div className='pagebase'>
            <StatementComponent statements={statements} />
        </div>
    );
}


export default CompanyDetails;
```

```
function StatementComponent({ statements }) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I've added them in and it looks a lot better now. However, my initial problem still stands. When I open the page, it will not (after the initial load with default null values) update the state with the data from the api call.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make any API call unless you press a button. By default, `appState.id` is `0`, and your `fetch` isn't called unless `appState.id > 0`.